# How to compare date from current year with column from database

Tags: php, date, compare

I'm trying get data from database dependent on  this condition:

```
 if($now < "'.$current_year . '-09-15")
```

I have to display data for last study session. 
I want to check if current date is less than 15.September current year and if it is to display data from database for study session.
But it's not showing correct result.
My code is:

```html
<?php
 $date = new DateTime("now"); 
 $now=$date->format('Y-m-d');
 $current_year = $date->format('Y');
 $last_year =  $current_year -1;   


 if($now < "'.$current_year . '-09-15") {

      $this->db->where('student_surveys.created_at < "'.$current_year . '-09-15" AND student_surveys.created_at > "'.$last_year . '-09-15"');
 }
 else {
     
      $this->db->where('student_surveys.created_at > "'.$current_year . '-09-15"');
 }
```

Comment: What result do you get?

Comment: I founded solution:         $this->db->where('student_surveys.created_at <',date("Y-m-d",strtotime($current_year."-09-15"))); It was because of the Codeigniter syntax :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an error in the formation of your date in the compare statement. When I tried to run the code, with a "true" printed in the if portion and "false" in the else, it returned false (which was incorrect output).
Try this:

```
<?php
 $date = new DateTime("now"); 
 $now=$date->format('Y-m-d');
 $current_year = $date->format('Y');
 $last_year =  $current_year -1;   
 $yourdate = $current_year."-09-15";
 if($now < $yourdate) {         
      $this->db->where('student_surveys.created_at < "'.$current_year . '-09-15" AND student_surveys.created_at > "'.$last_year . '-09-15"');
 }
 else {     
      $this->db->where('student_surveys.created_at > "'.$current_year . '-09-15"');
 }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working! I have a problem with quotes. :)